# How to convert creo EM map file into 3-dimension array

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, bioinformatics, correlation

To compute correlation to find maximal match of Amino Acids within unknown protein (crew EM map format file) - I need to convert EM map format file into 3D array - to manipulate possible correlations assuming the one with max correlation has best match. I use Python for my project.

My question: how to convert EM map file to 3D array of densities (i.e. 256x256x256 voxels)?

Comment: can you give more information about the EM map format? I couldn't find it after a quick search

Comment: Here are some explanations about EM map format, but I still couldn't parse them: 1) http://emdatabank.org/dictionaries.html
2) ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/emdb/doc/Map-format/current/EMDB_map_format.pdf
3) http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?pdbId=1DYL (download file->Download EM map)
4) http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/data/tutorials/semliki/semliki.html

Comment: https://salilab.org/modeller/9v1/manual/node317.html - The density class: handling electron microscopy density data
https://salilab.org/modeller/9v1/manual/node318.html - density() -- create a new density map
https://salilab.org/modeller/9v1/manual/node319.html - density.read() -- read an EM (electron microscopy) density map file
https://salilab.org/modeller/9v1/manual/node320.html - density.grid_search() -- dock structure into EM (electron microscopy) density map

Comment: Here how it usually looks like (in gray colour): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_function_prediction#/media/File:Computational_solvent_mapping_of_AMA1_using_FTMAP.TIF

Comment: I downloaded the density map for 1DYL and it's in binary, so it can't be parsed with just a script. Are your EM map files text or binary? If they are binary then you'll have to use some existing software like chimera or pymol, or modeller. If you end up having to use one of those programs you might be able to find more help on other forums since that's a question of program usage, not coding.

Comment: Here is the answer. There are at least 2 ways to parse an array from map file: 1) with modeller Python package (less friendly, I didn't succeed); 2) with  mapParser library of TemPy package: import numpy as np;
from TEMPy.MapParser import MapParser;
from scipy import ndimage;

emMap1 = MapParser.readMRC('/Users/leon/Downloads/EM/ALA/1S4Y-12.map');
map1 = emMap1.getMap();
flat1 = map1.flat;     # to flatten n x m array into 1-dimensional, since required next step is convolution with another parsed array. I put ";" to delimit commands, in Python - to remove them.

Comment: And here is less friendly ability to do the same with modeller package: 
from modeller import *
log.verbose()
env = environ()
den = density(env, file='1cuk-a2.mrc', em_density_format='MRC',
   voxel_size=1., resolution=8., em_map_size=40,
    cc_func_type='CCF', density_type='SPHERE')

Comment: @rbierman: thanks a lot. You provided me directions for further investigation.

Comment: great, thanks for posting your findings here!